# RecyclerView content disapears on device rotation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

Im doing an activity to show a profile that contains some cards with sports related to it, the idea is to see three cards at a time and be able to scroll the cards to see the next ones.

This is the code on the profile activity where I take the `RecyclerView` and set the `linearLayoutManager` and the `adapter`:

```
    private lateinit var sportRV: RecyclerView
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_profile)
        sportRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVSport)

           ... Some Other Code ...

        val sportModelArrayList: ArrayList<SportModel> = ArrayList()
        sports.map { sportModelArrayList.add(SportModel(it)) }
        val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)
        sportRV.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
        val sportAdapter = SportAdapter(this, sportModelArrayList)
        sportRV.adapter = sportAdapter
}
```

This is the `adapter` class:

```
class SportAdapter(private val context: Context, sportModelArrayList: ArrayList<SportModel>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<SportAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
        private var sportModelArrayList: ArrayList<SportModel>
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_view, parent, false)
            val lp = view.layoutParams
            lp.width = parent.measuredWidth / 3
            return ViewHolder(view)
        }
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            val model: SportModel = sportModelArrayList[position]
            holder.sportName.text = model.sportName
        }
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return sportModelArrayList.size
        }
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val sportName: TextView
            init {
                sportName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.sportName)
            }
        }
        init {
            this.sportModelArrayList = sportModelArrayList
        }
}
```

This is the section of the `profile_activity.xml` where the RecyclerView is used:

```
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/idRVSport"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
```

The RecyclerView works when I have the device verticaly, but the cards disappear when I rotate it, although the `onCreateViewHolder` function is still called, and the CardViews are created, just not shown. The cards reappear when I put it back vertically

Comment: Try this: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states

Comment: Use SavedInstanceState for any data you need to preserve through a screen rotation or after your app is put in the background and then restored. This is explained in the Android documentation. Alternatively, data that is backed up to a database or other file can be retrieved in `onCreate`, but it's better to put that retrieval in a ViewModel to avoid having to read from disk after each screen rotation.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I already tried saving and restoring the state, but that is not the solution to my problem, as it is not related to keeping the previous state or values, I perfectly can create again the cards each time as the values are static and their sizes should be recalculated.